# Jenkins "internal" pipeline script producing errors when running sh steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've been experimenting with creating a new pipeline, using the built-in pipeline editor (i.e. not from SCM). The strange bit is that, when I run *any* `sh` step, I receive the following error:

> sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")

This comes from the following MWE:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "FOO!"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The odd bit is that my pipeline scripts that *are* coming from SCM are working just fine, despite the fact that they have loads of shell scripts.

Running Jenkins 2.73.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this was caused by the pipeline name having an apostrophe character in it. Renaming the build solved the issue.